# Does Object.keys() work in Internet Explorer 9 for built-in objects?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, ecmascript-5

The Object.keys() method works fine for me with code like this:

```
var foo = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
console.log(Object.keys(foo).length);
```

However, Object.keys() returns a zero-length array for built-in objects with code like this:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>

<head>

<title>Object.keys()</title>

</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(Object.keys(window.document).length);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Am I missing something? I'm using Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421.

---

Postscript: I'm still not clear why this (for example):

```
    for (prop in performance.timing) {
        if (performance.timing.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            console.log(prop); 
        }
    }
```

...produces nothing in IE9, whereas this works fine:

```
for (prop in performance.timing) {
    console.log(prop); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript, there are *native objects* and *host objects*. In general, you can rely on things like `Object.keys` working with native objects, but not with host objects. `window`, `document`, and others are host objects. IE in particular is well-known for its host objects not being native-like (host functions don't have the `call` or `apply` feature, etc.).

Alternately, of course, it could be that `document` has no *enumerable* properties. Most of the default properties of objects are non-enumerable and so don't show up in `Object.keys`. For instance, `Object.keys([]).length` and `Object.keys(new RegExp(".*")).length` are both `0` because neither has any *enumerable* properties even though they both have lots of properties (they have properties for all of their "methods", and of course the blank array has a `length` property and the `RegExp` has a `lastIndex` property).

---

**Update**: And in fact, it was the enumerable thing. Try this test:

```
alert(Object.keys(window.document).length);
window.document.AAA__expando__property = "foo";
alert(Object.keys(window.document).length);
```

For me, on IE9, those alerts are "0" and "1", respectively. So `window.document` supports `Object.keys`, it's just that `window.document` doesn't, by default, have any *enumerable* properties. (In contrast, on Chrome I get 65 enumerable properties to start with, and of course 66 once I've added my expando.)

Here's a rather more full test page ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/efili5)) (hacked-together quickly, not a thing of beauty):

```
window.onload = function() {

  document.getElementById('theButton').onclick = function() {

    if (typeof Object.keys !== 'function') {
      display("<code>Object.keys</code> is not a function");
      return;
    }
    showKeys("Before adding", Object.keys(window.document));
    window.document.AAAA__expando__foo = "bar";
    showKeys("After adding", Object.keys(window.document));
  };

  function showKeys(prefix, keys) {
    var p, ul;

    keys.sort();
    prefix =
      "[" + prefix +
      "] Keys on <code>window.document</code> (" +
      keys.length +
      ")";
    if (keys.length !== 0) {
      prefix += " (click to toggle list)";
    }
    p = display(prefix);
    if (keys.length !== 0) {
      ul = document.createElement("ul");
      ul.innerHTML = "<li>" + keys.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
      ul.style.display = "none";
      document.body.appendChild(ul);
      p.onclick = function() {
        ul.style.display =
          (ul.style.display === "none") ? "" : "none";
      };
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
    return p;
  }

};
```

Comment: Why is `document` a host object? I thought `window` was the only host object. Can you place a link to something authorative explaining what a host object is

Comment: @Raynos: http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_4 (also see point 4.3.8). `document` is not part of the ECMAScript specification. It is provided by the browser (the environment)

Comment: @Raynos Because it's not defined in the ECMAScript standard. The ECMAScript standard states that a host object is any object whose semantics are *not* fully defined by the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Ah `host` means not owned by ecma or the js engine but part of the browser.

Comment: @Raynos: Browser or whatever the host environment is, yeah. As the spec says somewhere, "All non-native objects are *host objects*."

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks. It's puzzling that the (second) JScript example in the Microsoft Object.keys documentation implies it will work with window.document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff688127.aspx. They say the Object.keys argument '... can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.'

Comment: @Sam: So that suggests that it's just that `window.document` doesn't have any *enumerable* properties on it (on IE9). And in fact, that seems to be the case: I've just updated the answer, with an example page demonstrating `Object.keys` on `window.document` and adding an enumerable property to it.