# Object.keys not working in internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a program to return a list of keys from dictionary. The Code works correctly in Chrome, Opera and Firefox but not Internet Explorer.
I have added alert comments to close down where the issue is. Below is the code causing the problem. The alerts are shown in the order

- App Initializing
- Getting JSON
- Got JSON
- Got Keys (Does not show in IE)

I found a similar Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356722/does-object-keys-work-in-internet-explorer-9-for-built-in-objects) but I believe in this example that this isn't the correct question as I created the dictionary so it is a native object.

I am no longer sure that Object.keys is the problem so here is a link to the full page. 
I JavaScript is in page to make it easier to view

http://www.londonlayout.co.uk/dev/live.htm

```
 var myApp = {
    init: function () {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        alert('App Initializing');
        $.getJSON('data/data.json', function (raw) {
            alert('Getting JSON');
            myApp.data = raw;
            $.each(myApp.data, function (code, details) {
                try {
                    myApp.nameDict[details.name] = code;
                }
                catch (e) {}
            });
            alert('Got JSON');
            myApp.names = Object.keys(myApp.nameDict);
            alert('Got Keys')
            def.resolve();
        });
        return def.promise();
    },
    data: {},
    nameDict: {}
}
```

Comment: If prior to IE 9, here's the solution:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys as Object.keys(); does not work on below IE9 version

Comment: I am using version 10

Comment: Click on the top right cog. then "About Internet Explorer"
Says version 10.0.9200.16686

Comment: Ok So I have checked and there is another page I have built that uses Object.keys and works successfully on my version of internet explorer. However there is something that is making this line not work

Comment: IE6+ support: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303271/3078787

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`Object.keys` is [not avaiable in IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). As a simple workaround you could use:

```
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = function(obj) {
    var keys = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(i);
      }
    }

    return keys;
  };
}
```

Here is a more comprehensive polyfill:

```
// From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
if (!Object.keys) {
  Object.keys = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,
        hasDontEnumBug = !({toString: null}).propertyIsEnumerable('toString'),
        dontEnums = [
          'toString',
          'toLocaleString',
          'valueOf',
          'hasOwnProperty',
          'isPrototypeOf',
          'propertyIsEnumerable',
          'constructor'
        ],
        dontEnumsLength = dontEnums.length;

    return function (obj) {
      if (typeof obj !== 'object' && (typeof obj !== 'function' || obj === null)) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
      }

      var result = [], prop, i;

      for (prop in obj) {
        if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)) {
          result.push(prop);
        }
      }

      if (hasDontEnumBug) {
        for (i = 0; i < dontEnumsLength; i++) {
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, dontEnums[i])) {
            result.push(dontEnums[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return result;
    };
  }());
}
```

Comment: In your first code section you have a line that says only use this code if object.keys is not present. once you have created a work around why would you not use it for all cases

Comment: @PeterSaxton because the shim is likely to be a lot less performant than the native version.

Comment: I had actually always assumed in-built functions came with a lot of baggage to check for every possible eventuality resulting in a slower overall process. That's quite a revalation

Comment: @PeterSaxton Yeah, and those checks for "every possible eventuality" will probably catch a bunch of stuff that most developers will miss. You really want to make sure that those "edge cases" are handled.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if you have access to lodash you can use [keys](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keys). e.g.

`_.keys(yourObj);`