# how to write a patch for Object.keys call failing in IE 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

**Background Information**

I'm having the same problem that's described here:
[Object.keys not working in internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912932/object-keys-not-working-in-internet-explorer)
Essentially, I'm trying to call Object.keys but it's failing in IE.

I've tried to adapt the solution proposed in the above post to my code, but it's not working.

Here's what the original code looks like - I'm only showing the code that surrounds the call to Object.keys: (works in chrome)

```
    for (var key in res) {
         if (Object.keys(res[key]['associated_users']).length > 0 ) { 
               //do something here to build htmlstring with data
         } else {
              htmlstring += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
         }
    } //end for loop
```

In IE 9, the system fails on the line that calls the Object.keys method.

I tried to add the following logic before the loop inside the ajax success handler to check if the browser supports Object.keys:

```
         var len = 0;             
         if (!Object.keys) {
               var temp = keyslengthforIE(res);
               len = temp.length;
         } else {
               len = Object.keys(res[key]['associated_users']).length;
        }
        if (len > 0 ) {
               //do something here to build htmlstring with data
         } else {
              htmlstring += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
         }
```

And here's what the new function "keyslengthforIE" looks like:

```
function keyslengthforIE(obj) {
    var keys = [];  
    for (var i in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        keys.push(i);
      }
    }
    return keys;
}
```

**Problem**

There are two problems with my code that I don't know how to fix.

1. IE still complains when it sees the call to Object.keys. 
   I get the error "Object.keys: argument is not an Object" and it points to line 319.  Line 319 is this:

   len = Object.keys(res[key]['associated_users']).length;
2. The len that comes back from the new function is actually wrong.  I know it should be 10 but I'm getting 1.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT 1

Now that I know it IS supported in IE 9, i see my mistake. 
Will post answer

Comment: `Object.keys` is available in IE9, your problem is that `res[key]['associated_users']` is not an object

Comment: @adeneo doh!  ok.  I see what you mean now.  Please see edit 1

Comment: If you want to patch the missing method in older browsers, just use the [standard polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill) that creates the `Object.keys` function instead of writing a specific `keyslengthforIE` and testing which to use in front of every call.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the original code:

```
   for (var key in res) {
         if (Object.keys(res[key]['associated_users']).length > 0 ) { 
               //do something here to build htmlstring with data
         } else {
              htmlstring += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
         }
    } //end for loop
```

to look like this:

```
for (var key in res) {
  if ( ( res[key]['associated_users']) && (Object.keys(res[key]['associated_users']).length > 0 )) {
               //do something here to build htmlstring with data
         } else {
              htmlstring += "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
         }
    } //end for loop
```