# Collapses not working on IE11 (Object.keys: argument is not an Object)

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

Collapsible(to hide and show data) is working fine in other browsers(opera,chrome).But coming to IE `onclick`(on company as shown in figure) data is showing (expanding) ,Onclick on same tag/button(company) data is not hiding.In console error is showings as `Object.keys: argument is not an Object`

[image: error in console]

I found related question [Object.keys not working in internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912932/object-keys-not-working-in-internet-explorer)
 here but not applicable to my code(didn't help me).

Comment: You may want to read about [why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Answer (score 5):

As this is tagged with "bootstrap-4" I'm assuming it's related to [this bug in Bootstrap 4.1.0](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26320) where all collapsibles were unclosable in IE11.

More specifically, it was line 334 in Bootstraps `js/src/collapse.js` that was causing the problem. It was changed from 
`...typeof config === 'object' && config` to 
`...typeof config === 'object' && config ? config : {}`


Quoting [this page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26266): 
"If config is not an object, this is false. In IE, Object.keys(false) results in an error, while modern browsers return []"


The bug was fixed in subsequent versions. I had the same problem in a project recently and updating Bootstrap to version 4.1.1 fixed the problem.

(Update package.json with `"bootstrap": "v4.1.1"`(or later) and run `npm install`.)

> TL;DR: It's a Bootstrap bug. Update Bootstrap to version 4.1.1 or later.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know! Thanks so much!