# Bootstrap 4.1.3 Dropdown Menu Not Working in IE11 - Throws an Exception

Tags: internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap 4.1.3 and IE 11. I have created a Modal Dialog and the Modal Dialog has a Dropdown Menu. The Dropdown menu works fine in Google and Edge but not IE 11. I have researched and tried many solutions including those found here in Stack Overflow, but nothing is working.

Here is the basic dropdown code:

```html
<!-- Drop Down Menu -->

                <div class="d-flex align-self-end">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"> 
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbardrop">
                            <img src="Images/KoKoPelli.jpg" class="profile-picture"/>
                        </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Newsfeed</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One Drive</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sites</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>                    
                </div>
```

Here is the specific dropdown code:

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="Departments" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">Departments</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="Resources" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal"  onclick="showResourceHeader()">Resources</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="Procedures" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">Procedures</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="News" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">News</a></li> 
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="Newsfeed" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">Newsfeed</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="OneDrive" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">OneDrive</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link menuItem" id="Sites" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyNNSModal" onclick="hideResourceHeader()">Sites</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the entire project on JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tsmolskow/aq9Laaew/276201/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Bootstrap bug and many users had faced this issue before.

The fix is already available for this issue.

Please refer links below may help you to solve your issue.

(1) [Collapses not working on IE11 (Object.keys: argument is not an Object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676321/collapses-not-working-on-ie11-object-keys-argument-is-not-an-object)

(2) [fix issue related to Object.keys and Dropdown issue #26291](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/26291)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not getting that type of error - the error I get is this - Unhandled exception at line 1553, column 13 in http://localhost:59185/Scripts/bootstrap.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Exception thrown and not caught

Comment: When I try to make a test on my side, I find that I am not able to see the dropdown in IE but it is also not giving any error. I click on menu and for the first time it works but from second time it is giving this error. 'Object.keys: argument is not an Object'

Comment: Where are you seeing that error - in Developer Tools interface?

Comment: Yes, I can see that error in developer tools. Here you can check it. https://i.postimg.cc/9QxLDVBC/5.png

Comment: Before you ask, -1 because your posting links to vague discussions instead of clear answer. SO is for ANSWERING, not copy-paste links...